# How to repeat a code for multiple times and store the output of each iteration in the same dataframe?

Tags: r, iteration, getvalue

I am asking two questions:

1. How to run a code for multiple times?
2. How to store the output of each iteration in the same dataframe?

I have 3 outputs in my code: `mae`,`rmse` and `per_metrics`. I only want `per_metrics` for my final output for every iteration, and store the results from each `per_metics` for my overall output out of all the iterations.

```
    getValue <- function() {
    mae <- mae(dp$true_norm, dp$dp_threshold_norm)
    rmse <- rmse(dp$true_norm, dp$dp_threshold_norm)
    per_metrics <- c(mae,rmse)
return(i)
    }
result <- replicate(10, getValue())
```

N.B. Number of iterations = 10

This is only part of my code, I have the same input for all iterations but a noise adding mechanism `rlaplace()` between the input and output. So I get a different result in every iteration.

Comment: Look at the documentation of `replicate`, `sapply` and `lapply`.

Comment: To complement Roman, check your function and use of `{modelr}`. `mae()`and `rmse()` expect a model and data. The documentation shows an example. If you want to run your `getValue()` function with the same inputs, you will be generating the same results. The `per_metrics`  (return) variable is currently a vector, i.e. constructed with c(). Thus, think about coding this already as a data frame. It is not considered best practice to "grow" data frames as R memory management being a bit impolite.  But for 10 iterations it will work. Please note that you loop thus, result[i,] <- return-from-loop.

Comment: @Ray, probably OP is using Metrics package

Comment: In eirther case, your function will return THE SAME results whatever the circumstate, unless the input are altered.

Comment: I have the same input for every iteration but I am adding random noise every time so I get different results so as different MAE and RMSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a reproducible example, the following uses an example from the `{Metrics}` package documentation to construct your dataframe `dp`. Augment as appropriate.

Further you need to provide parameters to your function. In this case we supply the data frame `dp` (which you call in your function).

Lastly, `replicate()` returns an array/matrix. We reformat this into a "long" format and then coerce it to a data frame.

```
library(Metrics)

# simulate the data -----------------------------------------
actual <- c(1.1, 1.9, 3.0, 4.4, 5.0, 5.6)
predicted <- c(0.9, 1.8, 2.5, 4.5, 5.0, 6.2)

dp <- data.frame(
    true_norm         = actual
  , dp_threshold_norm = predicted
)

# make function work -----------------------------------------
getValue <- function(dp) {          # we define a parameter dp for the function
     mae <- mae(dp$true_norm, dp$dp_threshold_norm)
     rmse <- rmse(dp$true_norm, dp$dp_threshold_norm)
     per_metrics <- c(mae,rmse)
     return(per_metrics)            # return value 
}

# apply function multiple times with replicate()
# check this to understand the returned data format
replicate(n = 10, expr = getValue(dp))

# result ---------------------------------------------
## store in variable
result <- replicate(n = 10, expr = getValue(dp))

## coerce to "long data frame"  - here we set ncol 2 for 2 variables
result <- matrix(result, ncol = 2)

## coerce to data frame
result <- as.data.frame.array(result)
```

This yields:

```
result

          V1        V2
1  0.2500000 0.2500000
2  0.3341656 0.3341656
3  0.2500000 0.2500000
4  0.3341656 0.3341656
5  0.2500000 0.2500000
6  0.3341656 0.3341656
7  0.2500000 0.2500000
8  0.3341656 0.3341656
9  0.2500000 0.2500000
10 0.3341656 0.3341656
```

You can now rename the columns as required.

Comment: If my input changes in every iteration, does this mean I should include the `dp` inside `function(dp) {}` along with the parameters, and remain the same for the rest of your suggested code?

Comment: Apologies, took a while to come back. The idea of a function is to perform an operation. Thus, in general `input --> function --> output`. It is difficult to judge from your example how/what changes with every iteration. But conceptually, I would say yes. You could of course only provide the parameters (objects, e.g. vectors, values) that change/are relevant. Good luck with it!